# Free API for historical weather US data?

Tags: python, r, data

I am trying to retrieve a free R-Python API that provides historical weather data in US.

In fact `wunderground` API is no longer available.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use [NCEI Data](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/support/access-data-service-api-user-documentation)

And use ["httr" package](https://www.programmableweb.com/news/how-to-access-any-restful-api-using-r-language/how-to/2017/07/21) to access the API in r.